# Checking sftp connectivity

Tags: ssh, firewall, sftp

I can connect to the remote server using following command...

```
sftp abc@255.136.181.123
```

But this works from server A and if I use the same command on Server B it does not work.

1) What changes needs to be done by the remote server host to enable server B to be able to connect as well?

2) How do I check the difference from Server A and server B if the service is enabled on server B?

The ping to remote server IP does not work from both the servers and that is not required as well.

Comment: Define _"doesn't work"_ first.

Comment: What OS are the servers running ?

Comment: I am asked for the password after the line # Connecting to 255.136.181.123... # but on second server I am not asked for the password, I have to kill the command using Ctrl + C # using centOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Practical Solution

Verify that the SSH service is offered on that IP by performing a port scan. If you're not knowledgeable with port scanners, just download the Nmap pack with frontend from http://nmap.org/download.html and perform a standard scan.

If the service is not up, you need to talk to the IT staff in charge of managing that server.

Odds are, SSH is running but not on the default port. A Port scan should reveal the current listening port.

Another possibility is that the SSH daemon on Server B restricted login to certificate users. In that case, you need a public/private SSH key pair.

You can create one following this tutorial:
http://jaybyjayfresh.com/2009/02/04/logging-in-without-a-password-certificates-ssh/

Once you have your key pair, you can contact IT to tell them to add your public key to Server B authorized certificates.

### How to contact IT

If you can't find the SSH listening port like this, you can formulate a request to the IT staff in this manner

*"I need to be able to transfer files via SFTP to Server B. Can you please put the SSH service up if it isn't and tell me the listening port? In case there is a Whitelist set up, please add my Server to it*

*In the event that Server B is using a certificates authentication scheme, please add my public key to your authorized keys list (attached to the email).
"*

It is possible Server B has a list of allowed ips to connect to the SSH daemon, the "whitelist" part of the request should take care of that.

While you're at it, ask for a user/password if you don't have a centralized authentication backend.

Comment: `telnet ip.add.re.ss 22` is just as effective as a port scan and is unlikely to get the remote systems admin irritated with you by scanning their systems. IN this case the OP is not the admin of the remote system so we can't really help.

Comment: i'm suggesting that the daemon is **not** running on port 22. It could be any port really.

Also, there are a number of things that can be done before contacting IT. 

The less work he needs to have the other side perform, the quicker he will solve his problem.

Comment: Please take a look [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) and [here](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/876/edit-powers-activate-removing-hi-thanks) regarding your regards and tagline/signature - they are discouraged here.

Comment: If someone started remote scanning my systems they would have their IP address blocked very quickly.

Comment: Fair enough on the tagline policy.

Well, your infrastructure is probably structured enough that a problem like the OP's wouldn't happen. He's been tasked with a problem that can't be solved with the amount of information he has and delegating the issue to a third party is not a real solution. He needs first to gather information, and then act. If it's a public machine, it gets port scanned every day of the week. If it's not public and they belong to the same corporate network, he has reasonable cause for performing the scan.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not the admin of the remote server B there is little you can do. Your best course of action at this point is to contact admin of server B and tell them what is happening and work with them to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a firewall problem. In that case you need to request a firewall change to open from your ip to 255.136.181.123 port 22 protocol TCP.

Try running
 sftp -v abc@255.136.181.123
to see if you get any more information.

Comment: What would be the exact command to allow port 22 access to my IP?

Comment: That depends on what firewall or other access control is in use to stop your IP from connecting. The remote server admin is the best person to know or find that out.

Answer (score 0):

Its not about sftp i think.

Its about network connectivy.

Have you firewall on  255.136.181.123 ?

Comment: I do not control that server. I need to request for a change to remote server admin. I want to know what needs to be requested.